# Define prop's type for any Function React Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm tying to type Component's props, where `func` could be **any** function passed down from it's parent

```
interface TProps {
    func?: Function
    children?: ReactNode
}
```

Component:

```
return (
    <button
        onClick={props.func}
    >
        {props.children}
    </button>
)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

Argument of type 'Function | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: void) => void | PromiseLike) | null | undefined'.

What type should I use to define that `func` equals any function?

Comment: Please check this https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/typescript-pass-function-react. It might be helpful

Comment: you can add   onClick: () => void; or onChange: (id: number) => void  in this way.
You can refer this
https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally (not necessarily React), you could express the type for any function like

```
fn: (...args: any[]) => any
```

Comment: that's  wrong way to add type. you can add   onClick: () => void; or onChange: (id: number) => void  in this way.
You can refer this
https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet

Comment: @VijayPalaskar that was the point of the question, being able to describe _any_ function, with or without the argument or return values.The validity of the pattern is a different story. It might be a good idea to use different callbacks for different events if that's the case, but we don't have enough code here to decide on that

Answer (score 1):

change your Interface:

```
interface TProps {
    func?: () => void, // now in () you can pass any argument type, also in place of void, you can define any return type
    children?: ReactNode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the way that's not recommended.
change your interface to define in the following ways

```
    /** any function as long as you don't invoke it (not recommended) */
      onSomething: Function;
     /** function that doesn't take or return anything (VERY COMMON) */
      onClick: () => void;
     /** function with named prop (VERY COMMON) */
      onChange: (id: number) => void;
    /** alternative function type syntax that takes an event (VERY COMMON) */
       onClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void;
```

**You can refer this**

**https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet**